# document.forms["button1"].submit() not work when timer expired

Tags: javascript

When timer expired form not submited. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
    <title> 
        How to call PHP function 
        on the click of a Button ? 
    </title> 
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">   
    <h4>
        How to call PHP function 
        on the click of a Button ? 
    </h4>
    <form action="test1.php" method="post"> 
        <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1"
                class="button" value="Button" /> 
    </form> 
    <div id="timer"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var start = new Date();
        var x=setInterval(function() {
            // check time elapsed given target time of 10 mins from now
            var timeLeft = (6000 - (new Date() - start))/1000;
            // update timer
            document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = Math.floor(timeLeft/60) + ":" + Math.floor(timeLeft%60);

            // check if timer has elapsed, and submit form
            if (timeLeft < 0) {
                document.forms["button1"].submit();
            }
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to "submit" the button, not the form.  You can *click* a button, but you can't *submit* one.  The submit event is for forms.

(Side note: Open your browser's debugging console and observe that `document.forms["button1"]` returned `undefined` because there's no *form* with that identifier.  Always check the console for errors when something isn't working.)

Give the form an identifier and update that line of code to fetch it by that identifier:

```js
var start = new Date();
var x=setInterval(function() {
    // check time elapsed given target time of 10 mins from now
    var timeLeft = (6000 - (new Date() - start))/1000;
    // update timer
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = Math.floor(timeLeft/60) + ":" + Math.floor(timeLeft%60);

    // check if timer has elapsed, and submit form
    if (timeLeft < 0) {
        document.forms["form1"].submit();
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<form action="test1.php" method="post" id="form1"> 
  <input type="submit" name="button1" id="button1" class="button" value="Button" /> 
</form> 

<div id="timer"></div>
```